# python - Flask basic auth testing with pytest

Tags: python, testing, flask, pytest

I'm currently using Flask-HTTPAuth for basic authentication within my project. I've tested it by hand using curl and base64 tokens and it does indeed work. However I'm running into problems creating tests proving it works. This is my current test and it always turns back 401:

**class TestLoginApi**

```
def setup(self):
    myapp.app.config.from_object("config.TestingConfig")
    self.app = myapp.app.test_client()
    client = MongoClient(myapp.app.config['DATABASE_URL'])
    db = client.get_default_database()
    assert list(db.collection_names()) == []

    db.users.insert_one({'name': 'testuser', 'password': 'testpassword'})

def teardown(self):
    client = MongoClient(myapp.app.config['DATABASE_URL'])
    client.drop_database(client.get_default_database())

def test_not_logged_in(self):
    rv = self.app.get('/api/v1/login/')
    assert rv.status_code == 401

def test_correct_password(self):
    d = Headers()
    d.add('Authorization', 'Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk')
    rv = self.app.get('/api/v1/login/', headers=d,
        content_type='application/json')
    assert rv.status_code == 200
```

I've also tried changing the following:

```
def test_correct_password(self):
        d = Headers()
        d.add('Authorization', 'Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk')
        rv = self.app.get('/api/v1/login/', headers=d,
            content_type='application/json')
        assert rv.status_code == 200
```

to this with no success:

```
def test_correct_password(self):
         rv = self.app.get('/api/v1/login/', headers={"Authorization": "Basic {user}".format(user=base64.b64encode(b"testuser:testpassword"))})
         assert rv.status_code == 200
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: If my answer was correct, please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to simplify this question some more, to show only the auth issue. For example remove anything to do with Mongo.

Answer (score 17):

You can test authorization like this:

```py
import base64

valid_credentials = base64.b64encode(b"testuser:testpassword").decode("utf-8")
response = self.app.get(
    "/api/v1/login/",
    headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + valid_credentials}
)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

I think you would enjoy [my github project](https://github.com/mojotti/restful_api_with_mongo_db), which has a tons of different tests for Flask-HTTPAuth.

Comment: My issue was with using an incorrect pymongo query, sorry. instead of 'name' it should of been 'user'.

Comment: OK, no problem.